# Save Control Panel search filters? Craft 4

Tags: control-panel, search

I love the new control panel search filters. However, I see no facility to save them, and nothing in the documentation. Is there way to do this?
[image: Control panel search filter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Craft 4.4, it's not possible to save filters. Pixel & Tonic [plans to add this feature](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/11215) in a future release, though AFAIK no specific target version has been made public.

In the interim, you might consider creating custom element sources as stand-ins for oft-used filters. Custom element sources (which are available to all authors) can be created by site admins via the "Customize sources" button in element indexes. These sources use the condition builder similarly to the filters, and are saved to the project config.

[image]